# jQuery - cannot get variable inside hover function (mouseleave)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover, mouseleave, mousehover

I need to pass value of `current_src` to mouseleave function.

console.log returns `undefined`.

```
var current_src, swap_src;
jQuery(".browseProductImage").hover(
    function(){
        var current_src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
        var swap_src = jQuery(this).next().attr('src');
        jQuery(this).attr('src', swap_src); 
    },
    function(){
        jQuery(this).attr('src', current_src);
        console.log(current_src)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second `var` for `current_src`, you want to use here the upper scoping one variable:

```
var current_src, swap_src;
jQuery(".browseProductImage").hover(
    function(){
        current_src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
        var swap_src = jQuery(this).next().attr('src');
        jQuery(this).attr('src', swap_src); 
    },
    function(){
        jQuery(this).attr('src', current_src);
        console.log(current_src)
    }
);
```